# table of repeated values in R to determine frequency table

Tags: r

My data frame is of two columns as

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(5,8,5,6,6,8), freq = c(1,2,2,3,3,1))
```

How can I make a frequency table look like

```
id freq
  1 2 3
5 1 1 0
6 0 0 2
8 1 1 0
```

Any help please?

Comment: ~~~~~~ `table(df)`

Comment: got this error:

Comment: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: Try `with(df, table(id, freq))`

Answer (score 0):

```
> id <- c(5,8,5,6,6,8)
> freq <- c(1,2,2,3,3,1)
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, freq))
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> table(df)
   freq
id  1 2 3
  5 1 1 0
  6 0 0 2
  8 1 1 0
```